# Why isn't sinon replacing the actual function call?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, twilio, sinon, stub

My function is:

```
const PhoneNumber = require('awesome-phonenumber');
const twilio = require('twilio')(process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);
const { twiml } = require('twilio');

exports.incoming = (requestBody) => {
  const MessagingResponse = twiml.MessagingResponse;
  const VoiceResponse = twiml.VoiceResponse;
  const pn = new PhoneNumber(requestBody.Body, 'US');
    return global.db.Conference.create({})
      .then((dbCreate) => {
        conferenceId = dbCreate.id;
        // Call originator
        return twilio.calls.create({
          to: requestBody.From,
          from: requestBody.To,
          url: `${process.env.API_URL}/calls/conference?id=${conferenceId}`
        });
      })
```

My test is:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const twilio = require('twilio')(process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);
const { twiml } = require('twilio');

const SmsController = require('../../../controllers/sms');
const twilioIncomingSmsReq = require('../../mocks/twilioIncomingSmsReq');

describe.only('Sms Controller', () => {
  let messagingResponseMessageStub;
  let conferenceCreateStub;

  beforeEach(() => {
    messagingResponseMessageStub = sinon.stub(twiml.MessagingResponse.prototype, 'message').returns(true);
    conferenceCreateStub = sinon.stub(global.db.Conference, 'create').resolves({ id: 1 });

    return;
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    messagingResponseMessageStub.restore();
    conferenceCreateStub.restore();
    return;
  });

  it.only('should call the originator and recipient', () => {
    let requestBody = _.clone(twilioIncomingSmsReq);
    console.log(twilio.calls);
    let twilioDialStub = sinon.stub(twilio.calls, 'create').resolves(true);
    console.log(twilio.calls);

    return SmsController.incoming(requestBody)
      .then(() => {
        sinon.assert.calledWith(twilioDialStub, {
          to: requestBody.From,
          from: requestBody.To,
          url: `${process.env.API_URL}/calls?id=1`
        });

        sinon.assert.calledWith(twilioDialStub, {
          to: '+number',
          from: requestBody.From,
          url: `${process.env.API_URL}/calls?id=1`
        });

        twilioDialStub.restore();

        return;
      });
  });
});
```

But in my code, the actual `twilion.calls.create` function is called. Not the stub. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`twilio` refer to different objects in these modules. `require('twilio')` is factory function. It's expected to create a new object even when it's called with same arguments, `require('twilio')(...) !== require('twilio')(...)`.

Consider exporting `twilio` instance, at least for testing purposes:

```
const twilio = require('twilio')(process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, 
...
exports.twilio = twilio;
```

Comment: You’re saying I should export it from where?

Comment: You need to export `twilio` from a module where you use it in `incoming` function. I guess it's `.../controllers/sms`.